# query to add a new column based on the result of the other field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have a table

```
id  amount_spend
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
```

I want to add a third column called `category` and it should display:

- high (if amount_spend>30),
- medium(amount_spend>20 and<30) and
- low (amount_spend>20).

Please let me know how to add it in a select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, 
       amount_spend, 
       case
          when amount_spend > 30 then 'high'
          when amount_spend > 20 and amount_spend <= 30 then 'medium'
          else 'low'
       as category
from the_table;
```